# Evaluate signatures logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I need some help of the logic experts. I would like to evaluate the following signatures $\sigma$, such that $|\sigma^{Op}|=2$ and $t$ is a $\sigma$ term. Sometimes there are no solutions and sometimes more.

[image]

The countable set $\mathbb X=\{x^0,x^1,x^2,...\}$ (the numbers should be above, I do not know how to do that in latex) of symbols is called variable.

A signature is a pair $\sigma=(\sigma^{Op},ar) $ where $ar:\sigma^{Op}\rightarrow \mathbb N$ which gives the arity of the symbols and the elemnts of $\sigma^{Op}$ are operation symbols.

I have no idea how to evaluate the signatures, may you could show me that. For me it is also not not clear what this numbers above the variables exactly mean, may you have an idea?

Maybe the following defintion might be helpful: The set of all $\sigma$ terms is the smallest language over the alphabet $\sigma^{Op}\cup X$ which satisfy

(i) Every variable is a $\sigma$ term.

(ii) If $f\in\sigma^{Op}$ and $k=ar(f)$ and $t_1,...,t_k$ are $\sigma$ terms, then $ft_1...t_k$ is a $\sigma$ term

Answer (score 0):

*Comments*

The "language" $\sigma^{Op}$ has two operations symbols : $|\sigma^{Op}|=2$ means that the *cardinality* of the set $\sigma^{Op}$ is $2$.

It seems to me that they are : $f$ and $g$, i.e. $f,g \in\sigma^{Op}$.

The "arity" function is missing, but from the example it seems to me that :

> $ar(f)=ar(g)=2$.

The countable set of symbols $X=\{x_0,x_1,x_2,...\}$ is the set of variable; the index simply denotes the place in the listing (or sequence).

Consider the first *term* :

- $t=fx_1x_1c$;

what is $c$ ? If my assumptions are correct and the arity of $f$ is $2$, this means that :

- $t=f(x_1,x_1)c$ is not syntactically correct.

The second one can be "read" as :

- $t=f(x_{17}, g(x_9,c))$; it makes sense, but still we have the "undefined" symbol $c$.